# Binding resource property to DataContext property

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I was wondering if I could have a child window model in main window resource section and have its properties bound to main model. I have a simple string property on first model and string `DependencyProperty` on second and tried to bind this way:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowModel x:Name="MainWindowModel"/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <local:SecondWindowModel x:Key="SecondWindowModel" SecondString="{Binding FirstString}"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

`SecondWindowModel` is a `DependencyObject` and `SecondString` is a `DependencyProperty` as WPF requires. But `SecondString` is always null, its setter is never called. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that WPF will instanciate the MainWindowModel viewmodel correctly as the Window's DataContext.
But your SecondWindowModel viewmodel being a resource, is actually a **static resource**.
And in C# a static class is initialized only when you first use it.
I'm not sure if WPF initializes its static resources upon declaration. 
You can add a static constructor to SecondWindowModel with a break point and check if it is actually initialized before MainWindowViewModel or not at all.

Comment: A ( very! ) clunky way to do it would be to add SecondWindowModel as a control's datacontext, give a x:Name ( like x:Name="localContext" )  to your Window and bind SecondString ( like "{Binding ElementName=localContext Path=DataContext.FirstString}" ). But honestly, I don't think a WPF's viewmodel is meant to be used this way.